# array in javascript is not working properly, i need t

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

```
<script>
f = new Array();
f.push('h');
f.push('a');
f.push('i');
f.push('l');
f.push('e');
f.push('r');
f.push('i2');
f.push('s');
t = f.length;
face = f[Math.floor(Math.random() * t)];
document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = '<img src="' + face + '.png" alt="something" />';
</script>
```

It does not work
i am trying to make an array that randomize the images and shows them to the user, but it is not working and i dont know why

Comment: Does your html have an element with the id img? If so, is this script tag below it in the page?

Comment: Your javascript looks fine. Maybe you're running it too soon - for example before the page has loaded? Try putting the script right before the closing body tag.

Comment: Define "not working"! I ran your js in browser console and confirm that it picks a random value from the array.

Comment: I tried it and worked. Thanks

Comment: Does `id="img"` exist before this code runs? Also what is it? Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer here was to make sure the code was being run after page load

```
<body>

...

<script>
  f = new Array();
  f.push('h');
  f.push('a');
  f.push('i');
  f.push('l');
  f.push('e');
  f.push('r');
  f.push('i2');
  f.push('s');
  t = f.length;
  face = f[Math.floor(Math.random() * t)];
  document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = '<img src="' + face + '.png" alt="something" />';
</script>

</body>
```